# Ampersand in 5th column and at the end of the line

Tags: fortran, fortran90

I came across some code today that looks like this:

```
      subroutine sub(hello,world,this,routine,takes,a, &
     &   crazy,large,number,of,arguments,              &
     &   so,many,that,it,gets,split,across,four,       &
     &   lines)
```

It seems that the ampersands in the 5th column are in case the user
wants to compile the code with a f77 compiler -- My question is whether
this is legitimate (standard conforming) fortran 90 code.  I suppose that
it probably isn't standard conforming f77 code since the trailing ampersands
aren't in column 73 either...but if they were, would this be a standard way to make free-format and fixed-format compilers happy?  In other words, does the fortran 90 standard say that &'s in the middle of a line are simply ignored (or something to that effect)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The & is the Fortran 90 free-form *continuation character*.  The compiler will behave as if the lines are concatenated by matching the location of the trailing & with the leading & on the next line.  Since Fortran is happy to ignore spaces between tokens what you have posted is a way of writing a very long statement across a number of source file lines. (OP probably already knows all this, other readers may not.)

The snippet you show is definitely standard-conforming Fortran 90.  The standard defines a trailing & to be the continuation character.  If you want to split either a token (such as a variable name) or a 'character-context' (such as a string literal) across lines then the line onto which the continuation runs must start with an & and there must be no blanks inserted into the sequence of characters after the line-starting &.  I think that what you have posted sneaks into standard-conformity on the grounds that the successive &s might be considered to be not introducing any whitespace into the existing whitespace.

However, the line-starting &s are not required in your snippet.

Your snippet is definitely not standard-conforming fixed-format FORTRAN77.  However, most modern Fortran compilers will, unless you instruct them otherwise, take a relaxed view of this sort of 'not-standard-conforming' but 'obvious-what-is-meant' code and compile it quite happily.  Unless, that is, you try something odd like adding free-format code into an existing fixed-format source file, that's just asking for the compiler to have a hissy fit.

**EDIT**

My original answer failed to answer OP's question relating to moving the &s into the 73rd column as a tactic for creating code to keep fixed- and free-form compilation happy.  In FORTRAN77 continuation is marked by a character (any character) in column 6 of the continuing line.  That version of the language did not require any character at the end of the line being continued.  Again, I can't see anything wrong with putting an & in column 73.  As OP pointed out in a comment, fixed-form Fortran ignores any characters in col 73-80, and punched cards (ahh, happy days) had only 80 columns.

But I can't see anything to recommend this approach either.  I think that it is far preferable not to mix free- and fixed-form in the same source file.  All the current Fortran compilers will compile both forms in the same compilation.  But if you want to go ahead and mix the two, feel free to do so.

Comment: "Your snippet is definitely not standard-conforming fixed-format fortran77" -- If I push the trailing & into column 73, then I don't see any problem with it...

Comment: Sorry...I get so used to typing in my editor that I often end up accidentally submitting comments/answers on SO before I want to.

Comment: Thanks, I thought that was the case -- I was basically just trying to work out the rational for having a leading and trailing ampersand.  ( I don't recommend mixing free-form with fixed form either ), but I thought that I would ask to understand the rational behind the code being written this way.

Comment: Also, since you described the line-continuation mechanisms in F90 and F77 so well, you might want to mention that in F77 (fixed-source formatting) everything after column 72 is simply ignored -- which is why putting an ampersand in the 73rd column is OK.  (Just for completeness).  Great answer though.

Comment: Actually the rationale behind using this mixed continuation style is that it allows code to be `INCLUDE`-d by both fixed-form Fortran 77 and free-form Fortran 90 programs - not as obscure situation as one might think it is, especially while porting old code.

Comment: @HristoIliev Very interesting point ... I'll have to keep that in mind (since I work with both f77 and f90+ routinely)

Comment: You should also make sure that the code is valid Fortran 77, e.g. use `.LT.` instead of `<`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is conforming Fortran 90. If the first non-blank character on the next line is '&', the actual source text begins at the next non-blank character.

Answer (score 0):

High Performance Mark's answer is correct, however there's another important point about the fixed (F77) vs. free (allowed in F90 and later) format for continuations.  First, it looks to me like the code provided has the `&` character in the 6th column.  If it does, then it's almost F77-compatible; all that's required is to remove the trailing `&`'s at the end of the lines, or to move them to column 73.  And as Hristo Iliev noted, the use of an `&` at both columns 73 and 6 allows for a format that conforms to multiple Fortran standards, which can be useful for `INCLUDE` statements when coding in an environment that doesn't stick to a single standard.