# What is * in FORTRAN 77

Tags: fortran, symbols, fortran77

I'm using `Radau.f` Fortran ode-solver and my `gfortran` complains about the use of `*`

For example in:

```
            FF(I)=TI711*Z1I+TI712*Z2I+TI713*Z3I+TI714*Z4I+TI715*Z5I
     *               +TI716*Z6I+TI717*Z7I
```

what is `*` standing for? Is it an `&` such that the line should be:

```
            FF(I)=TI711*Z1I+TI712*Z2I+TI713*Z3I+TI714*Z4I+TI715*Z5I+&
     &               +TI716*Z6I+TI717*Z7I
```

Or is it supposed to be a comment or something else?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10584561/ampersand-in-5th-column-and-at-the-end-of-the-line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An asterisk in column 6 is a line continuation symbol and equivalent to `&` in *fixed form*. See [here](http://fortranwiki.org/fortran/show/Continuation+lines) for details. In fact, [*"any character (except a zero or blank)"*](https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/510918) is valid to indicate a line continuation.

An ampersand at the last position (and optionally in the beginning of the next line) does the same for *free form* Fortran. For fixed form, the second ampersand is mandatory.

An asterisk in the first column, on the other hand, denotes a comment line (as do `c` and `!`).

Comment: Awww, many thanks! It sounds reasonable, it is just I couldn't find it written. Thanks again.